# remove whitespaces with new line characters

Tags: python, regex, string, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a string that looks like that:

`"\n      My name is John\n      and I like to go.\n      blahblahblah.\n         \n\n      ".`

**Note - In this string example, there are 5 white-spaces after the new line character, but it can be any number of white-spaces after.**

I would like to replace those `"\n     "` substrings with just one space using a regex. I've been trying numerous combinations of regex and nothing seems to work right.

On of the regex's I found was `theString = string.replace(theString, '/\r?\n|\r/g', ' ')` But it didn't work also.

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Please read the [**re.sub** documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). It is not the same as JavaScript. There are no regex delimiters.

Comment: I feel like this is an XY problem. Why are you really doing this?

Comment: do you want to keep the newline and replace just the multiple spaces with one?

Comment: Can you show the exact output you want?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use regex, however you can do this:

```
>>> s = "\n      My name is John\n      and I like to go.\n      blahblahblah.\n         \n\n      "
>>> " ".join(s.split())
'My name is John and I like to go. blahblahblah.'
```

Comment: splitting won't add a space at the start and the end

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sub the newline  followed by spaces with a single space:

```
s="\n      My name is John\n      and I like to go.\n      blahblahblah.\n         \n\n      "
import  re

print(repr(re.sub(r"(\s+)",r" ",s)))
' My name is John and I like to go. blahblahblah. '
```

This does  *replace those "\n     " substrings with just one space*

If you want to keep a newline:

```
print(repr(re.sub(r"(?<=\n)(\s+)",r" ",s)))
'\n My name is John\n and I like to go.\n blahblahblah.\n '
```